# Samsung Laptop ODD Slot SSD installation

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, sata, connector

I have the following Notebook/Laptop: `NP550P7C-S0FDE` from Samsung.

It has two slots for hard-drives. The first one holds the HDD. In the second one I would like to place a SSD.

The problem is that there is no SATA data/energy interface. There is just some strange interface which name I don't know, but it says "HDD" on the board.

Can you tell me how I can connect the SSD to the laptop's mainboard?

[image]
[image]

Comment: To install a HDD or SSD in place of an optical disk drive in a laptop, you will have to place the 2.5" drive in a ***caddy*** (typically designed specifically for that laptop model/line).

Comment: @sawdust but there is a seperate place, especialy made for a second drive. if that works I don't want to exchange my optical disk drive for a SSD.

Comment: @sawdust my title says ODD, but i was just misguided by the arrow with the ODD label pointing to the second bay... I don't know why it even says ODD (Optical Disk Drive) in this case. You can see the label one inch from the red cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to pick up one of these:

[image: Samsung Laptop HDD Caddy apapter]

It looks like it's called an HDD Caddy Adapter. Also, some sources suggest that you may also need a caddy to attach the drive to slot. Which is very likely in your case, considering the mounted screw pattern in the empty slot match the pattern on your main HDD slot.

That one is from [here](http://www.pchub.com/uph/laptop/38-124881-22897/Samsung-Laptop-NP-RV511-RV511-HDD-Caddy-Adapter.html). You may need to check for a model specific version for your laptop.

Comment: exaclty what i needed. the shipping time is 10 -20 days... to Germany from PCHub. Do you know other terms/descriptions for this device? I searched on Ebay and Amazon Germany and didn't find it.

Comment: Try searching for <model number> caddy. That should give you everything you need.